# how to make Nested for-loops in Vb.net run faster on a powerful computer?

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I was trying to code 6-7 nested for-loops using Vb.net and tried to compile it on a i9-9900 computer with 32 GB of memory, but the run time takes too long! I ran the task manager and realized that the application is using only 10% if the CPU and less than 20 mb of memory! so is there a way to speed up the for-loops using more CPU power?

here's the sample of what I was coding:

```
Dim maxNo As Integer
maxNo = 200

For i = 0 To maxNo
 For k = i To maxNo
  For j = k To maxNo
   For l = j To maxNo
    For m = l To maxNo
     For n = m To maxNo
      For q = n To maxNo
          '......
      Next q
     Next n
    Next m
   Next l
  Next j
 Next k
Next i
```

Thank you in advance,
The Programmer

tried the code on a high spec. computer, but it still take too much time to complete the loops. I want to take advantage of the powerful PC to run the code faster.

Comment: The loops themselves probably aren’t the problem, more likely what you’re doing inside the loop.  There are some strategies possible maybe using threads or asynchronous methods but without seeing what you want to do it’s hard to help.

Comment: Your calculation is order N^7, so it will blow up rapidly with increasing N.  This is roughly the order of high-fidelity quantum mechanics simulations, so maybe there are some examples from that field of ways to deal with it, but mostly I think their strategies involve massive computing resources and limited N (or moving to other algorithms that are lower order than N^7).

Comment: If you can do anything to un-nest the loops, I would strongly recommend for you to do so.

Comment: If you think your current case has a manageable N and should fit the resources you have better, then the right thing to do is to profile it and look for opportunities to eliminate bottlenecks.  A couple of things to watch for in particular are opportunities to batch database or file access and issues of mismatching your access patterns and your data structures' optimal access patterns.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, my code should take 7 different rows in a 2d array and calculate the average for each column of the 7 rows. so these 7 loops are necessary to generate all possibilities of 7 rows in the array. e.g. 1234567, 1345678, 1456789..etc. I also added a condition to ensure that the sequence won't be duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simple matter is that your code will be single threaded, and your code show shows n^n type of problem.

Been a while since I done combinations and permutations (high school). But this code is WORSE then a n! (factorial) problem.

With just my lowly little laptop, you can in advanced compile, turn off "remove integer overflow checks - that will REALLY speed things up.

So, with your code like this:

```
    Dim maxNo As Integer
    maxNo = 150

    Dim startTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim MyTimeSpan As TimeSpan
    Dim mycount As Long

    For i = 1 To maxNo
        For k = i To maxNo
            For j = k To maxNo
                For l = j To maxNo
                    For m = l To maxNo
                        For n = m To maxNo
                            For q = n To maxNo
                                mycount += 1
                            Next q
                        Next n
                    Next m
                Next l
            Next j
        Next k
    Next i

    MyTimeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime)
    TextBox1.Text = $"Time to run loop = { (MyTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds) / 1000.0}"
    TextBox2.Text = mycount
```

To JUST a value of 150?

You are going to run a whopping and "astounding" 389 BILLION (yes, that is correct BILLION loops!!).

I get this:

[image]

I also found that running as x86 (forced x32 bit project) seems to run a good deal faster (no need to force the CPU to work with larger x64 bit side codes).

So, your problem?

You have to consider a smaller problem, or maybe perhaps adopt some type of parallal processing. but even with such a approach, your numbers are rather large, and thus you dealing with large amounts of processing.

Comment: I guess you are right, it is a huge number of loops! I thought that a powerful CPU is the solution, but it turned out that it's not. I will try to disable the integer check as you did and see if it can help, if not, I will see another algorithm for my problem. thanks a lot for your time :)